# Setting Welcome Sound in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, sound, startup

Can anyone help me to set a welcome sound in my laptop when operating system starts and ready to operate.

Answer (score 2):

As a part of boot ?

You need a sound file, an mp3 or whatever.

You then edit `/etc/rc.local` and add a line to play the sound.

```
gksu gedit /etc/rc.local
```

Add in these lines at the bottom, `exit 0` needs to be the last line

```
sleep 10 
aplay /path/to/your/sound.mp3
exit 0
```

You may need a longer or shorter sleep.

Answer (score 0):

IMHOP: messing with rc* should only be done when you really need to, not for playinf a startup sound. YMMV .A very easy to set up a startup sound would be to do the following:

> sudo apt-get install -y mpg123

Add an entry to session and startud such that the command reads like mpg123 ~/MyFile.mp3